# SQLite - selecting a member of a group without window functions

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to match file paths against each other, putting into the table `file_moves` the (`original_path`, `migrated_path`) pairs that match best. I am using levenshtein distance as a measure.
I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein_distance

con = sqlite3.connect("mig.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE file_migrated(repository, filename, migrated_path)')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE file_origin(filename, original_path)')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE file_moves(filename, original_path, migrated_path, repository)')
con.create_function('levenshtein',2,levenshtein_distance)
cur.execute("""
  WITH levenshtein_distances AS (
                     SELECT file_origin.filename, 
                        file_origin.original_path, 
                        file_migrated.migrated_path, 
                        file_migrated.repository,
                        levenshtein(original_path,migrated_path) as levenshtein_dist
                     FROM file_origin
                     JOIN file_migrated
                     ON file_origin.filename = file_migrated.filename
                   ),
      min_distances AS (
                   SELECT *,
                          first_value(levenshtein_dist) OVER (PARTITION BY original_path ORDER BY levenshtein_dist ASC ) as min_levenshtein
                   FROM levenshtein_distances
                 )
  INSERT INTO file_moves(filename, original_path, migrated_path, repository) 
                 SELECT filename, original_path, migrated_path, repository
                 FROM min_distances
                 WHERE levenshtein_dist = min_levenshtein
                 """)
```

This query looks to me syntactically correct but get

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

If I remove `min_distances` and just use `levenshtein_distances`, the query runs (but of course doesn't give me the results I want).

My SQLite version is 3.14.2, which is from before window functions were introduced (they were introduced in 3.25.0). Can I make this logic work without window functions? If not, how can I update the sqlite3 pakage of my python installation (Python 3.6).

Comment: Why don't you learn CTEs, rather than making a "nested dolls" query?

Comment: Please revise your question according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, it is not just about styling. Nesting subqueries is an SQL equivalent of "spaghetti code". It is much harder to debug issues in spaghetti code.

Comment: The code is executed successfully. No errors (well, except for your extra leading spaces).

Comment: @PChemGuy Ok, the sqlite3.dll my python is using is actually 3.14.2, which is from before window functions were introduced. Which means I can either 1) try to update that somehow or 2) make the logic work without window functions.

Comment: Please provide a table with representative sample input and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to do the query without window functions (due to my version not supporting them), and came up with this query which seems to work and is also not really any more complicated than the version with Window functions. I just use a GROUP BY instead, and join with the result of that.

```
  WITH levenshtein_distances AS (
                     SELECT file_origin.filename, 
                        file_origin.original_path, 
                        file_migrated.migrated_path, 
                        file_migrated.repository,
                        levenshtein(original_path,migrated_path) as levenshtein_dist
                     FROM file_origin
                     JOIN file_migrated
                     ON file_origin.filename = file_migrated.filename
                   ),
      min_distances AS (
                   SELECT original_path, MIN(levenshtein_dist) as min_levenshtein
                   FROM levenshtein_distances
                   GROUP BY original_path
                 )
  INSERT INTO file_moves(filename, original_path, migrated_path, repository) 
                 SELECT filename, levenshtein_distances.original_path, migrated_path, repository
                 FROM levenshtein_distances
                 JOIN min_distances
                 ON levenshtein_distances.original_path = min_distances.original_path
                 AND levenshtein_distances.levenshtein_dist = min_distances.min_levenshtein
```